# Apply filter and replace on same column together on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is sample dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["aa_1_a", 9],["bb_2_b", 2], ["3_c", 7], ["dd_4_d", 5]], columns=['A', 'B'])

>>> df
        A  B
0  aa_1_a  9
1  bb_2_b  2
2  3_c     7 <-- invalid row based on some regex
3  dd_4_d  5
```

on column A I need to perform some regax validation and need to extract digit and replace on same column

Expected output:

```
    A  B
 0  1  9
 1  2  2
 3  4  5
```

I managed to get above output by applying filter to validate regex and the doing replace function.

Is there anyway to get expected output in simple way

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the rest of your code please.

Comment: Can you double check your output? Shouldn't it be `9 2 5` for row b?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [**`pandas.Series.str.extract`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and then drop null rows:

```
df.assign(A=df.A.str.extract(r'[a-z]{2}\_(\d+)\_[a-z]')).dropna()

   A  B
0  1  9
1  2  2
3  4  5
```

You may need to change the regular expression, here is an explanation of the one I chose:

```
[a-z]{2}              # matches two lowercase characters a-z
\_                    # matches an underscore
(\d+)                 # matches one or more digits
\_                    # matches an underscore
[a-z]                 # matches a single character a-z
```

Here is an intermediate visualization of the series after using **`str.extract`**:

```
df.A.str.extract(r'[a-z]{2}\_(\d+)\_[a-z]')

     0 
0    1 
1    2 
2  NaN 
3    4
```

Any rows where a match is *not* found result in `NaN`, which we then drop in the final step.

Comment: Nice and clean.

Comment: When are you coming back to the `pandas` tag? :P

Comment: I pop back in every now and then. Will be more active when school begins in August :)

Comment: @user3483203 u are awesome, is there any way to extract multiple values out of it

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? There's always a way :)

Comment: @user3483203 Actually am looking to extract 10 digit phone number ex `1234567890` out of `+1(123) 456-7890`

Comment: I would personally replace all non-digits first and then try to match 10 consecutive numbers, something like `df.A.str.replace(r'[^\d]', '').str.extract(r'(\d{10})')`

Comment: wow +100 enjoying it, works perfect but its giving first 10 digits, we need last 10 digits means excluding country code I will work on it, plz let me know if you have already solution

Comment: To get the last 10 digits, just add `$` to the end: `str.extract(r'(\d{10})$')`